# Programmatically generate and assign ComboBox DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, datasource

I have a ComboBox named cmbWeekDays, a `WeekDay` class:

```
public class WeekDay
{ 
    public int Index;
    public string DayName;
}
```

and this FormLoad event:

```
List<WeekDay> days = new List<WeekDay>();
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Sat", Index = 1 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Sun", Index = 2 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Mon", Index = 3 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Tue", Index = 4 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Wed", Index = 5 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Thu", Index = 6 });
days.Add(new WeekDay { DayName = "Fri", Index = 7 });

cmbxWeekDays.DataSource = days;
cmbxWeekDays.DisplayMember = "DayName";
cmbxWeekDays.ValueMember = "Index";
cmbxWeekDays.Refresh();
```

I don't know why I get this weird result:

[image: output image]

Can any one explain me what's happening? and also how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding works with properties only. So, you have to declare properties in your data source class instead of fields:

```
public class WeekDay
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string DayName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good job, thanks. Why should it be the property? Why does it recognize property but not class fields?

Comment: @mahditahsildari: this is an implementation detail of binding engine (this detail is true for WinForms, WPF, and SL/WinRT). Working with properties provides data encapsulation, and, which is more important for data binding, changes notification mechanism via `INotifyProperyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try following ways may be it helps you. I am also faced same issue. but i wrote cmbyear.Databind() at the end it works for me. so try it once.

```
 DropDownList cmbYear = new DropDownList();
        cmbYear.DataSource = days;  
        cmbYear.DataTextField = "Year";
        cmbYear.DataValueField = "YearID";
        cmbYear.DataBind();
```

Comment: have you taken a look at the tag 'WinForms'? `DropDownList` and `DataBind` is in asp.net

Comment: ohh sorry @mahditahsildari. i was facing same problem in web application.